# How can I use a checkbox to switch between tabs when checked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I created a check box with two different sets of tabs that should be displayed or hidden depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.

> So far I have a checkbox that switches tabs when checked, but when I
>   uncheck it; it doesn't change back.

**What changes can I make to the code to make the checkbox checked on or off switch the tabs?**

**UPDATED:**https://jsfiddle.net/gtcf3y5d/

**HTML:**

```
        <li role="tab">
            <label data-target="#Custom">
                <input id="custom-mark" name="intervaltype" type="checkbox" />
                Custom
            </label>
        </li>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom">
            <h3>Custom...</h3>
        </div>

         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types">
            <h3>Regular</h3>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding: 1em;
}

/* Mimic Bootstrap's .nav-tabs>li(.active)>a 
   when using radio buttons instead of links in tab headers */
.nav-tabs>li>label
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>label
{
    cursor: default;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('input[name="intervaltype"]').click(function () {
    //jQuery handles UI toggling correctly when we apply "data-target" attributes and call .tab('show') 
    //on the <li> elements' immediate children, e.g the <label> elements:
    $(this).closest('label').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Radio buttons are not meant to be unchecked...

Comment: It's not a radio button it's a checkbox that should display content depending if it's checked on or off

Comment: Sorry but in your jsFiddle those are `radio`s...

Comment: I just updated the fiddle, I had the wrong fiddle on there, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Where's now your "Regular" checkbox/button/tab?

Comment: Also why are you missing the `<ul>` element?

Comment: Test the fiddle when you check the box - it switches tabs, I just want to target the li item instead of ul item. So that when I check on or off it switches tabs

Comment: Why do you use checkboxes at all? Isn't it simpler to register a LI click and depending on it's `data-*` attribute target the desired *panel* ID?

Comment: The checkbox is a stylistic choice. I'm guessing I need Javascript to make the checkmark change tabs backs and forth? Is this something you can figure out?

Comment: Checkbox is a really awful stylistic choice. Firstly cause (for stylistic purpose) on click you can change the clicked element's class, secondly cause checkboxes are meant for multiple selections > nothing you're currently doing.

Comment: I understand, but that's the choice I decided to make for the site. The checkbox should be off by default with default content and switch content on click. Can you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you are looking for.  All it's doing is passing the active class between the two:

```js
$('input[name="intervaltype"]').click(function () {

    $('#Custom').toggleClass('active');
    $('#Types').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 1em;
}

/* Mimic Bootstrap's .nav-tabs>li(.active)>a 
   when using radio buttons instead of links in tab headers */
.nav-tabs>li>label
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>label
{
    cursor: default;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div role="tabpanel">
    
        

        
        <li role="tab">
            <label data-target="#Custom">
                <input id="custom-mark" name="intervaltype" type="checkbox" />
                Custom
            </label>
        </li>
        

               
                
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom">
            <h3>Custom...</h3>
        </div>
        
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types">
            <h3>Regular</h3>
        </div>
        

    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more detail regarding why exactly your solution works. Providing detail regarding why your solution works and walking through your answer in more detail is always recommended.

Comment: Thank you! You really solved my problem. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

It has already stated in the comments that this really isn't the way to do it, but since you insisted on using the checkbox and bootstrap's tab, here is how to do so:

The way bootstrap's tabs works is that every element that should open a specific tab should be visible and clickable and have a `data-target` or `href` attributes that specify which tab should be visible upon click.

In order to emulate that behavior I had to emulate the way bootstrap show/hide tabs and take care of which tab to show/hide myself.

This is the code:

```js
$('input[name="intervaltype"]').click(function () {
    tabpanel = $(this).parents('[role=tabpanel]')
    tabpanel.find('.tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     tabpanel.find($(this).data('tab-checked')).addClass('active');
    } else {
     tabpanel.find($(this).data('tab-unchecked')).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 1em;
}

/* Mimic Bootstrap's .nav-tabs>li(.active)>a 
   when using radio buttons instead of links in tab headers */
.nav-tabs>li>label
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>label
{
    cursor: default;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel">
  <li role="tab">
    <label>
      <input id="custom-mark" name="intervaltype" type="checkbox" data-tab-checked="#Custom" data-tab-unchecked="#Types" />Custom
    </label>
  </li>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom">
      <h3>Custom...</h3>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types">
      <h3>Regular</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Again, I'm really AGAINST using this code.